# how to make a Venn plot of several groups

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(X1 = c(37L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, NA, 
11L, 12L), X2 = c(40L, NA, 35L, 35L, 35L, 34L, 29L, 28L, 28L, 
NA, 25L, 24L), X3 = c(60L, 44L, 49L, 41L, NA, NA, NA, 25L, 26L, 
NA, NA, 22L), T1 = c(19L, 55L, 47L, 46L, 36L, 42L, 25L, NA, 33L, 
42L, 50L, 22L), T2 = c(75L, NA, 32L, 44L, 27L, 31L, 17L, NA, 
18L, 45L, 10L, 11L), T3 = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, NA, 
46L, 36L, 42L, NA), P1 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
NA, 1L, 12L), P2 = c(40L, 44L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 29L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 55L), P3 = c(1L, 44L, 49L, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 25L, 26L, NA, 
NA, 66L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

group1 is X1,X2,X3
group2 is T1,T2,T3
group3 is P1,P2,P3

I am trying to make a Venn plot but I cannot figure out how to do it. I have read a number of questions here and also a very good tutorial here

https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/13301_6641d73cfac741a59c0a851feb99e98b.html

The first group has three replicate , the second group has 3 replicate and the third group has three replicate.

Comment: In order to make a Venn diagram you need to have some kind of number which shows overlap between your groups. How do you define overlap here?

Comment: @LyzandeR if we have value for 2 in the same row it means they overlap

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat your replicates as a single group, you can use my `nVennR` package:

```
library(nVennR)
nonas <- function(x) {unlist(as.list(na.exclude(x)))}
myV2 <- plotVenn(list(X=unique(c(nonas(df$X1), nonas(df$X2), nonas(df$X3))),  P=unique(c(nonas(df$P1), nonas(df$P2), nonas(df$P3))), T=unique(c(nonas(df$T1), nonas(df$T2), nonas(df$T3)))), nCycles = 20)
myV2 <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV2)
```

This will give you a quasi-proportional Venn diagram:

[image: threeset]

You can then examine each region:

```
>listVennRegions(myV2, na.rm = F)
$`0, 0, 0 ()`
[1] NA

$`0, 0, 1 (T)`
 [1] 19 47 46 36 42 33 50 75 32 27 31 17 18 45 10

$`0, 1, 0 (P)`
[1]  1 66

$`0, 1, 1 (P, T)`
[1] 55

$`1, 0, 0 (X)`
[1] 37 35 34 28 24 60 41

$`1, 0, 1 (X, T)`
[1] 11 22

$`1, 1, 0 (X, P)`
[1]  2  3  4 12 40 29 49 26

$`1, 1, 1 (X, P, T)`
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 25 44
```

As a curiosity, the `nVenn` algorithm has no limit for set numbers. You might perform the nine-set diagram, but it would be slow and give little information. It might go like this:

```
nonas <- function(x) {unlist(as.list(na.exclude(x)))}
myV <- plotVenn(list(X1=nonas(df$X1), X2=nonas(df$X2), X3=nonas(df$X3), T1=nonas(df$T1), T2=nonas(df$T2), T3=nonas(df$T3), P1=nonas(df$P1), P2=nonas(df$P2), P3=nonas(df$P3)))
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
myV <- showSVG(myV, opacity = 0.2, borderWidth = 0.5, setColors = c('#ff0044', '#ff4400', '#ff2222', '#44ff00', '#00ff44', '#22ff22', '#4400ff', '#0044ff', '#2222ff'))
```

Probably not very useful. If you want to know more, you can read the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html) for the package.

[image: nineset]

Comment: can you please explain what those numbers mean? I thought when I have three groups, then I can have what is overlapped between three. what are not and what are the total number of values , no?

Comment: something like this ? https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/14-venn-diagramm/

Comment: Yes, that would be the first picture. Group X includes all the elements in X1, X2 and X3. You can see which elements belong to each region below, after the `listVennRegions` command. The large numbers tell you how many elements are in the region. For instance, there are seven elements that are common to all three groups. The numbers inside the parentheses help you to locate each region. For instance, (1, 3) means "elements that belong to groups X (1) and P (3), but not to T (2). You can read the vignette for details.